# Error when deploy github site with maven

Tags: windows, maven, github, github-pages

With this maven pom file : https://gist.github.com/PhilippeGeek/44f62827bf73bc7d9368, I can't create a blob, the output is:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpeleoGraph 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- site-maven-plugin:0.6:site (default-cli) @ SpeleoGraph ---
[INFO] Creating 102 blobs
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.270s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 13 23:48:01 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.6:site (default-cli) on project SpeleoGraph: Error creating blob: Unexpected end of file from server -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: At least you should use the most up-to-date version which is 0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem come form an out-dated version of site-maven-plugin, you should use version 0.8 or more recent.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen with version 0.8 and 0.9 also, when the binary to be deployed to github is over about 30MB.

[Issue on github (see comments)](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/54)

[Reference to a work-around for reducing the size of the binary](https://github.com/fcrepo4/fcrepo4/commit/f31b4475875c97cc9984cf7ba8b2e73d9cea5751)